# Trying bolster mysql failover

Tags: mysql, failovercluster, database-cluster

My MYSQL servers are not configured properly with failover. I am thinking of using Redhat cluster or heartbeat. Also, I need to achieve all tasks w/ one floating IP since application does not know about multiple databases. Can someone suggest what route would be the very for best?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering), a data mining technique. You probably meant [tag:database-cluster] or [tag:failovercluster] instead. Yes, there is more than one term "clustering", not everybody is doing LAMP.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide on using regular replication I would recommend you using this:

[MHA tool for MySQL replication high availability](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/mha-for-mysql-053-released.html)

I didn't have a good experience with the ways you want to use, they are not as good as a cluster and not so much better than normal replication with the tool I posted. I do believe you should take a look at this tool and maybe stick with regular replication or jump to serious HA with MySQL cluster. Configuring the cluster might be hard but using [Several Nines Solutions](http://www.severalnines.com) things might be a bit easier.

Comment: You could think also about a multi-master replication, but I personally prefer MySQL cluster, since with multi-master you would end up also having replication to slaves from both masters to get HA, since multi-master would give you more inserts/sec only. anyway...